# Linux Commands in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, linux

I've decided to write some Linux commands in Python. Below is a list, along with some constraints (if you're unfamiliar with Linux, the top of the program along has a description about each command and what it does):

- `ls`: No constraints, just lists all files/directories in current working directory. No flags.
- `cd`: Can only pass `..` or another directory. No flags.
- `tree`: No flags or directories can be passed.
- `clear`: No constraints. No flags.
- `whatis`: Only defined commands can be passed. No flags.
- `cat`: Requires a *full* path to the file. No flags.

I would like feedback on all the functions embodied by the program below, but `whatis` in particular. I feel there is a better way than checking each individual function. Any and all recommendations are appreciated.

```
"""
This is a program to simulate a command line interface

Commands to reimplement:
    - ls ( lists all files and directories in current directory )
    - cd [directory] ( changes directory )
    - tree ( lists all files, directories, sub directories and files from current directory )
    - clear ( clears the console screen )
    - whatis [command] ( gives a description about the command )
    - cat [file] ( outputs the content of the file )
"""

import os

def ls() -> None:
    """
    Lists all files and directories in current directory
    """
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    for _, directories, files in os.walk(current_directory):
        for file in files:
            print(file)
        for directory in directories:
            print(directory)

def cd(directory: str) -> str:
    """
    Changes directory
    """
    current_directory = os.getcwd()

    if directory == "..":
        current_directory = current_directory.split("/")[:-1]
        current_directory = ''.join(f"{x}/" for x in current_directory)
        return current_directory
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        return directory
    return "Not a directory"

def tree() -> None:
    """
    Lists all files, directories, sub directories and files from current directory
    """
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    tab_count = 1
    print(current_directory.split("/")[-1])
    for _, directories, files in os.walk(current_directory):
        for file in files:
            print("|" + ("-" * tab_count) + file)
        for directory in directories:
            print("|" + ("-" * tab_count) + directory)
        tab_count += 1

def clear() -> None:
    """
    Clears the console screen
    """
    print("\n" * 100)

def whatis(command: str) -> None:
    """
    Prints a description about the passed command
    """
    if command == "ls":
        print(ls.__doc__)
    elif command == "cd":
        print(cd.__doc__)
    elif command == "tree":
        print(tree.__doc__)
    elif command == "clear":
        print(clear.__doc__)
    elif command == "whatis":
        print(whatis.__doc__)
    elif command == "cat":
        print(cat.__doc__)
    else:
        print("Not a valid command!")

def cat(file_path: str) -> None:
    """
    Accepts a path to a file, and outputs the contents of that file
    """
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            print(''.join(line for line in file))
    else:
        print("Not a file!")
```

Comment: `ls` is in the `os` module, you can use `os.listdir()` as well as `cd` for which you can use `od.chdir(path)` and for `clear` you may use `os.system('cls')`

Comment: @bullseye I realize those are available commands, but I tried to use the least amount of built in functions as I could.

Comment: @bullseye I think you mean `clear` instead of `cls`.

Comment: These commands look like meant for user interactive session. If that is the case, and you are not implementing them just as an exercise, I highly recommend using some more advanced python shell instead, such as ipython (available both for Python-2 and python-3, both for Linux and Windows, possible to install via pip). It features history access and search, tab completion of commands AND filenames, AND you can execute any actual linux shell command by simply prepending it with "!"

Comment: @bullseye You have those two confused. `cls` is for windows systems, and `clear` is for unix systems

Comment: @Linny exactly, I swapped them, `cls` for windows, `clear` for unix @marcelm

Comment: Your `ls`  takes no arguments. Is this by choice or did you simply not get around to that yet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a few comments. In general, your code deviates in surprising ways from the UNIX commands (and not just by missing flags or options):

- Your `ls` command does more than you claim it does. `os.walk` recursively "walks" down from the current directory, so it returns the content of all subfolders as well (without indicating in which subfolder each file or directory actually is).
- When working with paths you should use the library [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or at least `os.path` consistently. This allows your tools to also work in Windows, where the symbol separating paths is `\` and not `/`. You could use `os.path.join` in your `cd` function. However, all that code there is not needed, because `os.path.isdir("..")` is also `True`. Use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to get the absolute name of a path. In my home directory `os.path.abspath("..")` returns `/home`.
- Don't use special return values to indicate failure. What if I want to have a directory called `"Not a directory"`? It may not be the most common name for a directory, but it is at least a plausible name. Instead raise an exception and catch it in the surrounding scope.
- Note that your `cd` does not *actually* change the directory, so any calls in another function to `os.getcwd()` (like in `ls`) will still return the old directory.
- Instead of hard-coding 100 blank lines, try to find out how many lines the terminal has, as taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943921/4042267) by [@brokkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68595/brokkr):

  ```
  import os
  rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
  ```

  This probably works only on linux, though.
- Instead of reading the whole file into memory, joining it and then printing it, you can print it one line at a time. This is slightly slower, but has no memory limitation:

  ```
  def cat(file_path: str) -> None:
      """
      Accepts a path to a file, and outputs the contents of that file
      """
      if os.path.exists(file_path):
          with open(file_path, "r") as file:
              for line in file:
                  print(line, end="")
      else:
          print("Not a file!")
  ```
- As long as all your functions are defined in the same module, you can simplify your `whatis` command:

  ```
  def whatis(command: str) -> None:
      """
      Prints a description about the passed command
      """
      try:
          print(globals()[command].__doc__)
      except KeyError:
          print("Not a valid command!")
  ```

  Although this does open you up slightly to a user getting access to the `__doc__` attribute of any object in the global namespace (not sure if that is a security risk, though). To avoid this, you can also built a white-listed dictionary:

  ```
  DOCS = {f.__name__: f.__doc__ for f in [ls, cd, clear, tree, whatis, cat]}

  def whatis(command: str) -> None:
      """
      Prints a description about the passed command
      """
      try:
          print(DOCS[command])
      except KeyError:
          print("Not a valid command!")
  ```
- I think the docstrings should be in the same style as linux manpages, i.e. like you have in your module docstring.

Comment: You could say that the OP's code implements `ls -R` without the directory-name headers that actual `ls` prints when recursing.  Or more exactly: `find -printf '%f\n'` instead of `ls`.

Comment: @PeterCordes True. But then this should be reflected in the docstring.

Comment: Oh yeah, I assume it was unintentional, and certainly not very useful.  Just maybe fun to put it in those terms to illustrate to the OP what the symptom of their bug is, and what command they actually implemented by mistake.  (Maybe they do want to implement `find` next...)

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to programmatically get the docs, and one that I find cool to use is [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html).

`inspect` allows you, among other things, to check what's in your file (module):

```py
import inspect
import sys

docs = {}  # a dictionary
module = sys.modules[__name__]  # Gets us a reference to the current module

for name, object in inspect.getmembers(module):
    # getmembers returns the name of the object, then the object itself.
    if inspect.isfunction(func):  # Filter the functions
        docs[name] = object.__doc__
```

This can be rewritten as a dictionary [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
module = sys.modules[__name__]
docs = {name: func.__doc__ for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module) 
        if inspect.isfunction(obj)}
```

Then, this could be defined as a constant:

```py
module = sys.modules[__name__]
DOCS = {name: func.__doc__ for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module) 
        if inspect.isfunction(obj)}

def whatis(command: str) -> None:
    print(DOCS.get(command, "Not a valid command!"))
```

`dict.get` allows to specify a default value if the key is not in the dict (here, the error message).

This shows an alternative to your implementation, but I would not use it myself, for it's not so clear at first glance. What I like about it, though, is to have a constant dictionary, for this module is concise enough:

```py
DOCS = {
    'ls' = ls.__doc__,
    'cd' = cd.__doc__,
    'tree' = tree.__doc__,
    'clear' = clear.__doc__,
    'whatis' = whatis.__doc__,
    'cat' = cat.__doc__,
}
```

Comment: You already use `inspect`, so it might be worth to have a look at [`inspect.getdoc(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc).